# Hint for the way a fm receiver works

Tags: rf, radio, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

As far as I know , a simple AM receiver can consist of a LC filter(connected at antenna) which amplifies the selected frequency, a demodulator( a diode for example) which rectifies the signal,an amp and a/more speakers.Now how would a simple FM receiver work?Could I just have to tune the LC circuit at a corresponding frequency to receive FM? Or perhaps there is another way to do it?I looked on the web,but the only thing I could find were schematics that I don't understand.

Comment: You've just described a simple **AM** radio. FM demodulators are considerably more complex than a single diode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going in too much detail, just for basic understanding:

The simplest FM demodulator would project the RF signal on the slope of a low pass filter. When the frequency increases the amplitude of the LPF output will reduce, whereas when the frequency decreases the output of the LPF would increase, resulting in an AM signal which conveniently you already know how to demodulate.

A practical FM demodulater would probably consist of a band filter to discriminate the signal you are interested in from all the noise. Then the RF signal is usually mixed down to an intermediate frequency, this improves on the practical component values while being able to tune on a signal from a wide band. Then the above mentioned LPF to demodulate the audio signal.

Modern FM receivers "try to grab on to the IF signal" with a local oscillator. It tries to keep its local oscillator in sync with the IF signal. The control signal for the local oscillator closely resembles the audio signal. This is what is commonly called a PLL receiver (Phase Locked Loop).

Comment: You can project it onto the slope of a high pass filter too. The "detected" audio would be the phase inversion of the low pass filter but who cares +1

Comment: Say,if I used the "simplest FM demodulator" design,in order to tune to a particular frequency,I would need to modify the LPF,right?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say there @DanielTork

Comment: @Andyaka The music would be played in reverse too.

Comment: @jippie I never realized that LOL

Comment: This is all mixed up. The mixer and the bandpass filters all *precede* the demodulator.